LogAnalytic Alert Rule Suppression option
We have 1000+ azure log analytic workspace alert rules created with AzureRM templates and azurepiplines for our different projects. below is the ARM template used for all these alert rule creations and we have a parameter called "enabled" for enabling and disabling the alerts as needed.
But for further enhance this automation, we are trying to automate a way for our developers, so that they can suppress any specific alert rules triggering for a specific time from they addressed the issue to till the time  they are resolving the issue by enhancing the same arm templates  & pipeline approach itself. Also once the suppression time is over, the alerts should be in the enabled status and should trigger for the events.
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "actionGroupName": {
            "type": "string"
        },           
        "query": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "logAnalyticsWorkspaceId": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "AlertRuleName": {
            "type": "string"
        },    
        "tags": {
            "type": "object"
        },
        "schedule": {
            "type": "object"
        },       
        "severity": {
            "type": "int"           
        },                          
        "operator": {
            "type": "string"         
        },  
        "threshold": {
            "type": "int"
        },
        "autoMitigate": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": false
        },
        "enabled": {
            "type": "string"
        },        
        "customWebhookPayload": {
            "type": "object"
        },             
        "location": {
            "defaultValue": "[resourceGroup().location]",
            "type": "string"
        }    
},    
    "resources":[
        {
            "type":"Microsoft.Insights/scheduledQueryRules",
            "name": "[parameters('AlertRuleName')]",
            "apiVersion": "2018-04-16",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            "tags": "[parameters('tags')]",            
            "properties":{
                "displayName": "[parameters('AlertRuleName')]",
                "description": "[parameters('AlertRuleName')]",
                "enabled": "[parameters('enabled')]",
                "source": {
                    "query": "[parameters('query')]",
                    "dataSourceId": "[parameters('logAnalyticsWorkspaceId')]",
                    "queryType":"ResultCount"
                },
                "schedule":"[parameters('schedule')]",
                "action":{
                    "odata.type": "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Monitoring.Alerts.Models.Microsoft.AppInsights.Nexus.DataContracts.Resources.ScheduledQueryRules.AlertingAction",
                    "severity": "[parameters('severity')]",
                    "aznsAction":{
                        "customWebhookPayload": "{ \"AlertRuleName\":\"#alertrulename\", \"AlertType\":\"#alerttype\", \"Severity\":\"#severity\", \"Application\":\"#{appname}#\", \"Text\":\"#alertrulename fired with #searchresultcount records. #{alertDescription}#\", \"SearchQuery\":\"#searchquery\" }",
                        "actionGroup": "[array(parameters('actionGroupName'))]"
                    },
                    "trigger":{
                        "thresholdOperator": "[parameters('operator')]",
                        "threshold": "[parameters('threshold')]"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}


Hi @Vowneee, As per MS Doc, you cannot add the suppression configuration directly inside an alert ARM template. Instead, you can suppress alert notifications by disabling the alert rules at the beginning of the maintenance window and re-enabling them once the maintenance is over using the cmdlet: Update-AzActivityLogAlert -ResourceGroupName "Automation_RG" -Name "Sample-Alert" -Enabled:$false (use $true to enable and $false to disable).

You can use the PowerShell script here to enable and disable multiple alerts at the beginning of the maintenance window and re-enable them once the maintenance is over.

@venkat, we are already using az cli command to enable and disable the alert rules now. But its again a manual task which is outside of our centralized alert rule creation automation. Also since we have 1000+ alert rules created in this way, having another way of disabling alert may result in missing some scenarios or items and which may have additional effort to track the status of each alert rules.

To automate this process, you can also use an Automation Runbook to run the script at a scheduled time if you already know the maintenance period.

Yes.. This seems very helpful. We are planning to use same azure pipeline along with this Script. Can you share the entire script url . Also as we are using Linux based agents, whether the shellscript of the same available?

Have you tried the approach of passing suppression start time and endtime as a pipeline parameters of suppression window. @Vowneee

@jhanvi. yet to test as i have to try with Shell script than powershell script

Here is a PowerShell script to disable the alert until the maintenance period is over and automatically re-enable it once the maintenance is complete.
$resourceGroupName = "Automation_RG"
$alertRuleNames = @("Sample-Alert")  

function Disable-AlertRules {
    param (
        [string[]]$AlertRules
    )
    foreach ($alertRuleName in $AlertRules) {
        Write-Host "Disabling alert rule: $alertRuleName"
        Update-AzActivityLogAlert -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Name $alertRuleName -Enabled $false
    }
}
function Enable-AlertRules {
    param (
        [string[]]$AlertRules
    )
    foreach ($alertRuleName in $AlertRules) {
        Write-Host "Enabling alert rule: $alertRuleName"
        Update-AzActivityLogAlert -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Name $alertRuleName -Enabled $true
    }
}
Disable-AlertRules -AlertRules $alertRuleNames
Start-Sleep -Seconds 60
Enable-AlertRules -AlertRules $alertRuleNames

Write-Host "Maintenance completed. All specified alert rules have been re-enabled."

The script will automatically disable the alert and re-enable it once the maintenance period is completed. You need to specify the maintenance time using the Sleep command.
Start-Sleep -Seconds 60


Bash script
#!/bin/bash
resourceGroupName="Automation_RG"
alertRuleNames=("Sample-Alert")

# Function to disable alert 
disable_alert_rules() {
    for alertRuleName in "${alertRuleNames[@]}"; do
        echo "Disabling alert rule: $alertRuleName"
        az monitor activity-log alert update -g "$resourceGroupName" -n "$alertRuleName" --enable false
    done
}

# Function to enable alert 
enable_alert_rules() {
    for alertRuleName in "${alertRuleNames[@]}"; do
        echo "Enabling alert rule: $alertRuleName"
        az monitor activity-log alert update -g "$resourceGroupName" -n "$alertRuleName" --enabled true
    done
}
disable_alert_rules
# Wait for the maintanance period (in seconds)
sleep 60
enable_alert_rules
echo "Maintenance completed. All specified alert rules have been re-enabled."


Output:


So this sleep command need to keep on running in backend? In our cases some alert need to suppress for weeks, till the issue is completely addressed and we may have number of alerts in this way. So is it feasible with this sleep option as this need to run in backend ?

Yes, specify the time period in the sleep condition so that it triggers automatically.

seems bit complicated, as we have to automate this through Azure pipelines, not seems to be a solution to keep the sleep command in the execution for a long duration.

You can also use Azure Functions or Azure Logic Apps to handle the automation of alert enabling and disabling is more scalable and manageable. This approach allows you to handle long-term suppression periods effectively and integrates well with Azure Pipelines for a seamless CI/CD experience
